# Are you able to pass uri_file Inputs into an Azure ML Sweep Job?

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I've recently started working with the Azure ML python SDKv2.

I'm looking to fine-tune models with my sample of data and was hoping to incorporate different pre-trained models as starting points in my fine-tuning sweep job.

I have a normal fine-tuning pipeline working fine and have been using this guidance to attempt to convert my pipeline to have a sweep step which include choosing separate embedding dictionary starting points (embs are a registered datasets containing a dictionary of word embeddings). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-sweep-in-pipeline

I've attempted to use Choice to provide Input options as you do in a normal pipeline as well as trying to pass just the path strings. However, when I run I get the issue below.

```
Choice([Input(type = "uri_file", path = "azureml:embsa:1"),
        Input(type = "uri_file", path = "azureml:embsb:1"),
        Input(type = "uri_file", path = "azureml:embsc:1"),
        Input(type = "uri_file", path = "azureml:embsd:1")])

Invalid component job since input x for component job Y expecting data with types UriFile has been assigned literal value.
```

I'm assuming this is because the Choice object is doing something different than just iterating through the list provided, but not really sure I know where to look next.

My question is essentially, is it possible to pass registered datasets as a Choice into a sweep step? if so, how might this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not supported, we define search_space for hyperparameter sweep in inputs of train_model and call train_model.sweep() to create a sweep node based on train_model with specific run settings.

[image]